# Postgres: how to delete entries in multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, metadata, topological-sort

I have a task that to implement a 'rollback' (not the usual rollback) function for a batch of entries from different tables. For example:

```
def rollback(cursor, entries):
    # entries is a dict of such form: 
    # {'table_name1': [id1, id2, ...], 'table_name2': [id1, id2, ...], ...}
```

I need to delete entries in each table_name. But because these entries may have relationship between so a bit complex. My idea is in several steps:

1. Find out all columns from all tables that are nullable.
2. Update all entries set all columns that are nullable to null. After this step there should be no circular depends (if not, i think they can't be insert into the table)
3. Find out their depends and make a topological sort.
4. Delete one by one.

My questions are:

1. Does the idea make sense?
2. Has anyone done something similar before? And how?
3. How to query the meta tables for step 3? coz i'm quite new to postgresql.

Any idea and suggestion would be appreciate.

Comment: I have to ask - *why*? This is a sufficiently weird question that it's either an assignment, or one of those things where you have some problem to solve, you've decided this is the best solution, and you're asking us about a problem with the best solution. If it's the latter, it might help to explain the underlying problem, ie what you are trying to achieve as an end result by doing this.

Comment: Also, by "rollback" do you actually just mean "delete"? A rollback implies undoing changes or restoring what was there before. You just seem to want to delete a set of rows from different tables that may have inter-dependent foreign key relationships.

Comment: @CraigRinger thx for your reply. It's not a homework :) In fact I'm working on a import/export data project, there are numerous tables in the system, one may want to import/export data to/from some of them. There is one feature that is to undo the importation. So i use the name 'rollback', maybe not that proper :) any way, the problem is just to delete set of rows as you said

Comment: Well, that makes it easier. Record the order in which you insert the data and replay that order backwards when removing. Use an audit log.

Comment: @CraigRinger Hmm, I will try both of the methods, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) and (2) are not right. It's quite likely that there will be columns defined `NOT NULL REFERENCES othertable(othercol)` - there are in any normal schema.

What I think you need to do is to sort the foreign key dependency graph to find an ordering that allows you to `DELETE`, table-by-table, the data you need to remove. Be aware that circular dependencies are possible due to deferred foreign key constraints, so you need to demote/ignore `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` constraints; you can temporarily violate those so long as it's all consistent again at `COMMIT` time.

Even then you might run into issues. What if a client used [`SET CONSTRAINTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html) to make a `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE` constraint `DEFERRED` during a transaction? You'd then fail to cope with the circular dependency. To handle this your code must [`SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED`] before proceeding.

You will need to look at the [`information_schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) or the PostgreSQL-specific [system catalogs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html) to work out the dependencies. It might be worth a look at the `pg_dump` source code too, since it tries to order dumped tables to avoid dependency conflicts. You'll be particularly interested in the [`pg_constraint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html)
catalog, or its `information_schema` equivalents `information_schema.referential_constraints`, `information_schema.constraint_table_usage` and `information_schema.constraint_column_usage`.

You can use the either the `information_schema` or `pg_catalog`. Don't use both. `information_schema` is SQL-standard and more portable, but can be slow to query and doesn't have all the information `pg_catalog` contains. On the flip side, `pg_catalog`'s schema isn't guaranteed to remain compatible across major versions (like 9.1 to 9.2) - though it generally does - and its use isn't portable.

Comment: For 'NOT NULL REFERENCES othertable(othercol)' (1) and (2) will not touch it coz it's notnullable.